# PHP MySQL - Start from ID x

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm making a newssystem, the last ID (so the last news) must be at the top, and now I want that below the first news box (not in the same box as the last news) are coming the other news, so that the last ID is not included. I've no ideas.

Last news code:

```
<?php $last_news = mysql_query("SELECT FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"); ?>
```

Other news, below the last news: (?)

```
<?php $other_news = mysql_query("SELECT FROM news ...?"); ?>
```

Comment: What about indexing it ?

Comment: What are you meaning?

Comment: Security Warning, dont use mysql_ functions!!! I'm writing this 10 time today. Aren't you really reading documentations? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php? See the red big box? Nice one...?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `limit`with the offset 2

```
 <?php $other_news = mysql_query("SELECT FROM news order by id desc limit 2,numerOfNewsYouWillShow"); ?>
```

This will not show you the last news. but the news before. Hope I have understand your issue correct.

Please do not use `mysql_*` functions. The `mysql_` API is deprecated.

Comment: Please update Your answer with the note that mysql_ functions are deprecated and not safe anymore. +1 from me :).

Comment: @JacekKowalewski I have done.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is in stead of retrieving the data from the database in 2 queries is to retrieve the data once and then split it in php.

```
$last_news = array_shift($allnews);
```

Then `$allnews` will contain all the other news and `$last_news` the latest news article. This will also mean you only hit your db once which is better for scaling.

---

Please do not used the `mysql_*` functions. They are depreciated because of security issues. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [MYSQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) in stead

More info on shift function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Comment: @Jacek Thanks, that was the function I was looking for but couldn't find.

Comment: No problem, you welcome. +1 from me. You should also consider to write an information about `mysql_` deprecated functions, as I wrote in almost every comment. They are unsafe, and it is worth to note it here.

Comment: That is specifically why I didn't copy his code and worked from there but probably a good idea.

Comment: PS. You can take a look also at `array_pop`, `array_push`, and `array_unshift` functions. They are all dedicated for stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

below the last news, you can use

```
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

**id** **field**

23 last news     //ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

19 yesterday     //ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1

18 old

**for one query**

```
order by id desc limit 2
```